# GET api query interpretation of "/"

Tags: http, get

I'm using a GET api query. At one point, there is a part that goes as follows:

`"... %20customer_list:/serviced/& ..."`

I noticed that the query works with and without the "/". Is that always the case? What is that character used for then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will work without any problem but you must determinate if its required for you with "/" characters?  for example:

```
myfile.aspx?myValue=user%20customer_list:/serviced/&...
```

when you request the value of myValue you will get:

```
"user customer_list:/serviced/"
```

otherwise if you receive the value without "/":

```
"user customer_list:serviced"
```

this will cause a fail in your implementation?